# File placement for iPhone Applications

Tags: iphone, file

If your application accesses and edits an already existing file is it okay for that file just to be placed in the resources folder?

Comment: Do you mean the Apps document directory?

Answer (score 3):

No, because the app bundle is read-only on the iPhone. You would have to copy the file from the bundle to your app's documents directory on first launch. Use this code to find the documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```